# Unique increment for every each child records?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-relations

I'm trying to make relations between two tables, but I'm looking for the best way to do that.

So, my question is how to make a column to increment the values starting from 1 ?

Here is my database:

```
topics
 -id
 -name
 -alias

notifications
 - id
 - topic_id
 - topic_alias
```

For example,

```
+----+--------------+-----------+
| id | title        | alias     |
+----+------------+-------------+
|  1 | Topic 1      | TP1       |
|  2 | Topic 2      | TP2       |
|  3 | Topic 3      | TP3       |
+----+------------+-------------+
```

imagine that Topic 1 and 2 have 10 notifications, but Topic 3 doesn't have notification.

And now, if you create notification related to topic 3, I want to create increment field/column that will start with 1.

How can to do that ?

The point of this is to create pretty url that will associate the notification with the project, for example http://example.com/notification/TP1-5 where the 5 is the 5th notification in topic 1.

Thanks

Comment: Neither of your tables has a `title` column.  Please fix/clarify your sample data.

Comment: Why do you need this? Why not just use a foreign key to the topic ID?

Comment: you could also create a slug.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I want to create slug, but the point is that the slug should be like topic_alias-nth_notification, so my questions is how to increment the nth notification ? One way is, on inserting new notification, to count the number of notification for that field+1, but I'm not sure that this is a good idea, or ?

Comment: Just use the auto-increment ID in the slug. There's no need to restart for each topic.

Comment: @Barmar but the point is to restart for each topic :) This is the reason why I'm asking for resetting the counter :)

Comment: If the table is MyISAM you can use a secondary auto-increment. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: If not,there's no automatic way to do it. You'll need to do the counting in PHP and add the alias.

Comment: I wonder if such a simple concept could be explained in a simpler way. Anyway, just use a regular autoincrement and handle the display logic in your queries/application code.